# RawValue or NextValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, performancecounter, instrumentation

I have a very simple question, which I thought was answered before, but I just couldn't find any exact and simple reference to what I'm looking for.

I have a console utility app that, per input parameters, obtains a list of performance counters per web application or per windows service.

My simple question is: what counters should be read with NextValue and what counters with RawValue?

Since my utility needs to run fast (under 2 seconds), I want to read each counter efficiently. For example, I know that Process/% Processor Time must be read thru NextValue while Process/Working Set can be read thru RawValue.

I was trying to have my app to decide based on the PerfCounterType (NumberItems32, CounterXXX, etc), which can work, but I simply need exact simple direct information about how to read each.

My early conclusions seem to be that all must be read thru NextValue for improved accuracy, but since experience is that some can do RawValue, then better to get it thru the second and avoid the 1 second sleep required.

This is the potential list of counters and I obtained the Type:

```
# Bytes in all Heaps = NumberOfItems32
# Gen 0 Collections = NumberOfItems32
# Gen 1 Collections = NumberOfItems32
# Gen 2 Collections = NumberOfItems32
# Induced GC = NumberOfItems32
# of current logical Threads = NumberOfItems32
# of current physical Threads = NumberOfItems32
# of Exceps Thrown / sec = RateOfCountsPerSecond32
# of Exceps Thrown = NumberOfItems32
# of marshalling = NumberOfItems32
# of Sink Blocks in use = NumberOfItems32
% Processor Time = Timer100Ns
% Time in GC = RawFraction
Bytes Received = NumberOfItems64
Bytes Sent = NumberOfItems64
Cache % Process Memory Limit Used = RawFraction
Cache % Process Memory Limit Used = RawFraction
Cache Total Entries = NumberOfItems32
Cache Total Entries = NumberOfItems32
Cache Total Entries = NumberOfItems32
Channels = NumberOfItems32
Connections Established = NumberOfItems32
Context Proxies = NumberOfItems32
Current Queue Length = NumberOfItems32
Errors Unhandled During Execution = NumberOfItems32
Errors Unhandled During Execution = NumberOfItems32
Errors Unhandled During Execution = NumberOfItems32
Finalization Survivors = NumberOfItems32
Forms Authentication Failure = NumberOfItems32
Forms Authentication Failure = NumberOfItems32
Forms Authentication Success = NumberOfItems32
Forms Authentication Success = NumberOfItems32
Gen 0 heap size = NumberOfItems32
Gen 1 heap size = NumberOfItems32
Gen 2 heap size = NumberOfItems32
Handle Count = NumberOfItems32
Large Object Heap size = NumberOfItems32
Remote Calls/sec = RateOfCountsPerSecond32
Request Wait Time = NumberOfItems32
Request Wait Time = NumberOfItems32
Requests Executing = NumberOfItems32
Requests Executing = NumberOfItems32
Requests Executing = NumberOfItems32
Requests In Application Queue = NumberOfItems32
Requests In Application Queue = NumberOfItems32
Requests In Application Queue = NumberOfItems32
Requests Succeeded = NumberOfItems32
Requests Succeeded = NumberOfItems32
Requests Succeeded = NumberOfItems32
Requests Timed Out = NumberOfItems32
Requests Timed Out = NumberOfItems32
Requests Timed Out = NumberOfItems32
Requests/Sec = RateOfCountsPerSecond32
Requests/Sec = RateOfCountsPerSecond32
Requests/Sec = RateOfCountsPerSecond32
Sessions Active = NumberOfItems32
Sessions Active = NumberOfItems32
Sessions Active = NumberOfItems32
Thread Count = NumberOfItems32
Total Remote Calls = NumberOfItems32
Working Set - Private = NumberOfItems64
```

Comment: My initial thought is that whatever .NET code you write to process the raw values will be slower than code Microsoft wrote, which would be compiled with high optimization for the best performance.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397(v=vs.85).aspx#using_raw_performance_data_classes shows the 2 second wait between collection of raw counters for processor time counter data, so that wait appears to still be necessary whether you get raw or baked.

Comment: right, if it has to take 1 second, I cant go against that, but at least to do it the most performant as possible

Comment: Right--what I'm saying is that any .NET code you write to process RAW values will not be better performance-wise than the Windows code that does it.  Additionally, if you put in a mechanism for it to decide which type of counter to get, that is even more overhead.

Comment: Agreed. Then If I have the mapping between counter vs readmode at least I can hardcode it to reduce overhead.